# Windows forms Treeview refresh issue

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, refresh

I am using a `TreeView` to show a folderstructure. I dynamically create nodes in the `NodeMouseClick` event.

But even though the child nodes are populated, they are not visible in the treeview.

However, minimizing the window and maximizing it again solves this issue. Please let me know what I am doing wrong here. Please find below the code that I am using:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null && e.Node.IsExpanded)
        {
            treeView1.BeginUpdate();
            TreeNode node = e.Node;
            while (node.Parent != null)
            {
                node = node.Parent;
            }
            VcDetailsEntity detailsEntity = connectedVCs.Where(c => c.VCName == node.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            detailsEntity.VCBrowserPath = e.Node.Name;
            FolderBrowser cosmosBrowser = new FolderBrowser();
            List<FolderStreamEntity> folderStreams = folderBrowser.GetVcContentDetails(detailsEntity);
            e.Node.Nodes.Clear();
            foreach (var stream in folderStreams)
            {
                if (stream.IsDirectory)
                {
                    TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode();
                    treeNode.Name = stream.StreamName;
                    treeNode.Text = stream.QualifiedName;
                    treeNode.ToolTipText = stream.QualifiedName;
                    TreeNode dummyNode = new TreeNode();
                    treeNode.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)dummyNode.Clone());
                    TreeNode toUpdate = treeView1.Nodes.Find(e.Node.Name, true).FirstOrDefault();
                    toUpdate.Nodes.Add((TreeNode)treeNode.Clone());
                }
            }
            treeView1.EndUpdate();
            treeView1.Refresh();
        }
    }
```

I have tried the suggestions provided by Gnial0id, wpfnoop and LarsTech here below. But no luck. Temporarily I have resolved it by minimizing and maximizing the form programatically.

Comment: Have you tried the Suspend/ResumeLayout methods ?

Comment: Code seems to work.  Problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe try Invalidate() instead of Refresh()? Invalidate redraws the entire control, Refresh only the client area.

Comment: The Windows version is important.  Do try to limit the risk by moving the BeginUpdate() call after the dialog invocation.  And remove Begin/EndUpdate() completely and tell in your question whether that had any effect.

Comment: Tried doing all these suggestions. But not helping. Temporarily, I have managed it by minimizing and maximizing the window programmatically for a single time. After that it works for ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding below code bloc immediately after the code to add a New Node did the magic for me.

treeView1.SelectedNode = NodeToUpdate;

Here the NodeToUpdate is the node where the new child nodes are added.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's hard to figure out anything from the provided code snippet because many parts are missing. Also I don't quite understand why `TreeNode toUpdate = treeView1.Nodes.Find(e.Node.Name, true).FirstOrDefault();` is needed and then why you are cloning the node you just created etc. So I've prepared a sample test which is doing something similar and it **does not** experience the problem you are describing. Check it out and compare it to your code to find out what is wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Samples
{
    static class Test
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var form = new Form();
            var treeView = new TreeView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                var parent = new TreeNode { Text = "Parent#" + i };
                treeView.Nodes.Add(parent);
                for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
                {
                    var child = new TreeNode { Text = "Child#" + i };
                    var dummy = new TreeNode();
                    child.Nodes.Add(dummy);
                    parent.Nodes.Add(child);
                }
            }

            var random = new Random();
            int addCount = 0;
            treeView.NodeMouseClick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (treeView.SelectedNode == e.Node && e.Node.IsExpanded)
                {
                    treeView.BeginUpdate();
                    e.Node.Nodes.Clear();
                    int count = random.Next(20) + 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
                    {
                        var child = new TreeNode { Text = "AddChild#" + (++addCount) };
                        var dummy = new TreeNode();
                        child.Nodes.Add(dummy);
                        e.Node.Nodes.Add(child);
                    }
                    treeView.EndUpdate();
                }
            };

            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Ivan. Thank you so much for your effort on this. As another @Hans have notified earlier, it might be an issue with the version of the windows or a system specific issue. I checked your solution and i tried incorporating the changes.     I modified my code again to suit the way you have proposed. But it was not helping me. I figured out a way to come over this issue after a lot of trial and error method. The solution is to add a code block like this:  treeView1.SelectedNode = NodeToUpdate;  This have infact resolved the issue. Once again thanks a lot for looking into this issue.

Comment: Also to answer your query  in your previous comment,  The code block TreeNode toUpdate = treeView1.Nodes.Find(e.Node.Name, true).FirstOrDefault(); is not mandatory, we can use e.Node.Nodes.Add The earlier code(Nodes.Find()) was evolved as part of the struggle to make this event work. And also, the cloning was proposed by another website(link I dont remember) as a solution to the Treeview refresh issue as well as a best practice to update the Nodes.